# Show that $I(\gamma; z) = n$, where $\gamma(t) = z_0 + r e^{it}$, $t \in [0, 2\pi n]$, when $|z - z_0| < r$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $I(\gamma; z) = n$, where $\gamma(t) = z_0 + r e^{it}$, $t \in [0, 2\pi n]$, when $|z - z_0| < r$.

The index is defined as

$$I(\gamma; z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z_0}$$

I know it is a very simple problem, but I find no way to correctly prove it. Here is what I've done:

Let $z_0, z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z - z_0| < r$. If $z = z_0$ we are done, since $I(\gamma; z_0) = n$. Suppose then, that $z \neq z_0$. Define $\sigma(t) = \gamma(t) - z_0 + z$, $t \in [0, 2\pi n]$. Thus,

$$I(\gamma; z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma} \frac{dw}{w - z}  = n$$

Basically, I'm pretending to use that both $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ are homotopic to the point $z$. This seems correct to me, since $f(w) = \frac{1}{w - z}$ is not defined in $w = z$. The problem here, is that I'm not using the hypothesis $|z - z_0| < r$, meaning that everywhere in the complex plane, it is always true that

$$I(\gamma; z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z} = n, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$

(for the given $\gamma$ which is fixed in terms of $z_0$) which is of course not true, since for $z$ such that $|z - z_0| > r$, $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z} = 0$.

EDIT 1:

What if

$$I(\gamma; z_0) = I(\gamma; z) \Longleftrightarrow \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z} = \int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w - z_0} = (2 \pi i)n \Longleftrightarrow z_0 \in int(\gamma) \Longleftrightarrow |z - z_0| < r$$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very famous result says:

> If $a$ and $b$ belong to the same component of $\mathbb{C}-\gamma$, then $I(\gamma, a) = I(\gamma, b)$. Moreover, this index is 0 for the unbounded component of $\gamma$, whenever $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $\mathbb{C}$.

In your example, both $z$ and $z_0$ lie in the bounded component of $\gamma$. Hence their indices must be same. If a point lies outside the circle, then it is in the unbounded component and hence the index must be 0.

Reference:

[1] J. B. Conway, Functions of one complex variable, second edition, page 82.

Comment: This result if consistent with my last sequence of iff's. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes in this case.